# In R rgl, how to choose the position of tick marks in plot3d?

Tags: r, rgl

In R,

```
library(rgl)
m <- matrix(rnorm(300),100,3)
par3d(ignoreExtent=F)
plot3d(m,box=T,axes=F,xlab='',ylab='',zlab='')
axes3d(labels=F,tick=F,box=F)
gr <- grid3d('z')
par3d(ignoreExtent=T)
plot3d(cbind(m[,1:2],rgl.attrib(gr[1],'vertices')[1,3]),col='gray',add=T)
```

still prints the ticks with numbers:

[image: Box3D-1]

Shouldn't `tick=F` parameter in `axes3d()` get rid of the tick marks and the numbers?

I want to add the x and y axes at the bottom of the graph, not at the top. Also, when I add them using `axis3d()`, the ticks aren't orthogonal anymore, but inclined in 45 degrees relative to their plane, which I think is ugly.

```
par3d(ignoreExtent=F)
plot3d(m,box=T,axes=F,xlab='',ylab='',zlab='')
box3d()
axis3d('x--',labels=T,tick=T)
axis3d('y+-',labels=T,tick=T)
axis3d('z++',labels=T,tick=T)
gr <- grid3d('z')
par3d(ignoreExtent=T)
plot3d(cbind(m[,1:2],rgl.attrib(gr[1],'vertices')[1,3]),col='gray',add=T)
```

[image: Box3D-2]

If I have to go this second way, how to get rid of the front lines of the box? Or is there another way to print the default tick marks (orthogonal) in the desired position?

Answer (score 1):

Axes in `rgl` are somewhat confusing and not very flexible.  First, there are two different kinds:  those drawn by `axis3d`, and those drawn with `rgl.bbox`.  Only the first type pays attention to the `tick` argument, and your first example used the second type.

You can remove the ticks in the `rgl.bbox` axes by setting `marklen = 0, marklen.rel = FALSE`, but this has the unfortunate effect of putting the numbers right on the box.  There isn't a separate parameter to control placement of the numbers independent of tickmark length.   If you don't want numbers at all, use `xlen = 0, ylen = 0, zlen = 0`.

The `axis3d` axes are also not very flexible.  If you want to change their orientation, you'll need to modify that function.  The `mpos` array holds the coordinates of each tick; change it to make the ticks point the way you want.

Regarding the box:  it's fixed if you use `box3d()` to draw it.  If you want the `rgl.bbox` style, you'll have to use that function.  You could also use `segments3d()` and `mtext3d()` to construct your own axes, but they won't move around like the `rgl.bbox` axes.

Comment: It seems I can't add no axis to `rgl.bbox`, so it's useless to me. Also, to specify black numbers, the box also become black, which is stupid. Maybe I'll write something myself. Thank you!

Comment: I added `col='black'` and both the numbers (which were white) and the box itself (which was gray) became black. This is stupid, not the package itself.

Comment: I've looked at the help page, but since there was no `color` parameter in the function definition (in Usage), I thought they used the color in the ... (rgl.material), which says nothing of two colors. Good. Now I know that not always the necessary parameters will be in the Usage section. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169966/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-user2554330).